# Return variables from tkinter GUI to execute code and then print results to GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to coding so please forgive me for any simple oversights.
I am writing a program that query's my local SQL database and returns basic statistics on the data.  I am trying to build a simple tkinter GUI that will control the two variable factors and the print the results in text boxes.
I am currently stuck on getting the variables from the entry boxes.

I am using Python 3.6, my code is below.

Really appreciate any help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sc

engine = sc.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://DC2:password@SQLconn")


class SimLvGUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.parent.title("SimLv")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Enter FTR Source Sink")
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + W, pady=4, padx=5)

        entry1 = Entry(self)
        entry1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=5, sticky=N + W)

        lb2 = Label(self, text="Enter FTR Month as Number")
        lb2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N + W, pady=4, padx=5)

        entry2 = Entry(self)
        entry2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=1, padx=5, sticky=N + W)

        run_button = Button(self, text="Run")
        run_button.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=4, padx=5, sticky=N + W)
        run_button.config(command=self.on_button)

        lb3 = Label(self, text="Historic spot FTR stats")
        lb3.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, sticky=N + W)

        results1 = Text(self, width=30)
        results1.grid(row=6, column=0, rowspan=10, padx=5, sticky=W + N)

        lb4 = Label(self, text="Historic FTR clearing stats")
        lb4.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, sticky=N + W)

        results2 = Text(self, width=30)
        results2.grid(row=6, column=1, rowspan=10, padx=5, sticky=W + N)

        lb5 = Label(self, text="Last FTR clearing price")
        lb5.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, sticky=N + W)

        results3 = Text(self, width=30, height=10)
        results3.grid(row=6, column=2, rowspan=5, padx=5, sticky=W + N)

        lb6 = Label(self, text="High volume FTR clearing price")
        lb6.grid(row=11, column=2, padx=5, sticky=N + W)

        results3 = Text(self, width=30, height=10)
        results3.grid(row=12, column=2, rowspan=5, padx=5, sticky=W + N)

    def on_button(self):
        ftr_source_sink = self.entry1.get()
        ftr_month = self.entry2.get()

    def run_simlv(self):

    sql1 = ("SELECT Avg({0}) as {0} "
            "FROM dbo.FTR_matrix "
            "WHERE month(Trading_date) = {1} "
            "GROUP BY month(Trading_date), year(Trading_date) ORDER BY  
            year(Trading_date), month(Trading_date) "
            .format(ftr_source_sink, ftr_month))
    # Import FTR clearing data from SQL server.
    sql2 = ("SELECT Price "
            "FROM dbo.FTR_Reg "
            "WHERE FTR = '{0}' and Mth = {1} and HedgeType = 'OPT' and MW>0 and 
            Price>0 "
            "ORDER BY Mth, Yr ".format(ftr_source_sink, ftr_month))
    # Return most recent FTR clearing price.
    sql3 = ("SELECT DateAcquired, Mth, Yr, FTR, MW, Price "
            "FROM (SELECT m.*, row_number() over (partition by FTR order by 
            DateAcquired desc) as rn  "
            "FROM dbo.FTR_Reg m "
            "WHERE FTR = '{0}' and Mth = {1} and HedgeType = 'OPT' ) m2 "
            "WHERE m2.rn = 1 ".format(ftr_source_sink, ftr_month))
    # Return the highest volume FTR purchase
    sql4 = ("SELECT DateAcquired, Mth, Yr, FTR, MW, Price "
            "FROM (SELECT m.*, row_number() over (partition by FTR order by MW 
            desc) as rn  "
            "FROM dbo.FTR_Reg m "
            "WHERE FTR = '{0}' and Mth = {1} and HedgeType = 'OPT' ) m2 "
            "WHERE m2.rn `enter code here`= 1 ".format(ftr_source_sink, enter 
            code here ftr_month))

    # Output historic spot statistics
    print('Spot Price Statistics')
    ftr_month_value = pd.read_sql_query(sql1, engine)
    print(ftr_month_value.describe())

    # Output historic clearing statistics
    print('Clearing Price Statistics')
    ftr_clearing = pd.read_sql_query(sql2, engine)
    print(ftr_clearing.describe())

    # Output last clearing price
    print('Last Clearing Price')
    ftr_lastprice = pd.read_sql_query(sql3, engine)
    print(ftr_lastprice)

    # Output highest volume cleared
    print('Clearing Price at highest cleared volume')
    ftr_high_volume = pd.read_sql_query(sql4, engine)
    print(ftr_high_volume)


def main():
root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x600+200+50")
app = SimLvGUI(root)
root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `on_button` does nothing practical because `ftr_source_sink` and `ftr_month` live and *die* inside your function definition. Try saving them as attributes:

```
def on_button(self):
    self.ftr_source_sink = self.entry1.get()
    self.ftr_month = self.entry2.get()
```

so that you later can access them anywhere inside the class definition.

---

As a side note, if you decide for this approach, it is usually good practice to initialize those attributes inside `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    # your code
    self.ftr_source_sink = None
    self.ftr_month = None
```

Comment: you should definetly initialize them in _ _ init _ _ as you might get "Referenced before assignment" errors instead when using them somewhere else